# How to nest routing in Vue with many children?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, nested-routes

I have three main views that each holds its own mark-up and unique content. The plan was to handle it like this:
[image: overview over the views]

**View 1: Users**

List all users, links to each user, which is view 2. With a routerlink you go to view2.

```
<router-link v-bind:to="'/user/' + user.id">
```

**View 2: Albums**
List all albums for the user. Link to press to see each album which takes you to view 3.
I grab the id from url with

```
data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
```

this works fine, I then use the id to fetch data from an API.
The problem starts now when I want to nest a new layer down to view 3 (photoView).
Here I have a problem with nesting:
If possible I want to use a url like

```
"/user/:id/albums/:id"
```

**I have tried to set the routes to the this:**

```
{ path: "/user/:id/albums/:id", component: PhotoView },
```

And the router.link in view2 (albumview) to:

```
<router-link v-bind:to="'/user/' + id + '/album/' + album.id">
                  <p>{{ album.title }}</p>
                </router-link>
```

This doesn´t work.
I then tried to put the path to photoView as a child to the albumview, and this works.

```
{
    path: "/user/:id",
    component: AlbumView,
    ///
     children: [{ path: "/user/album:id", component: PhotoView }],
  },
```

**BUT PROBLEM now**. I render both views, the photoview just stack up under the albumview… as I in the albumview has the `<router-view></router-view>`

**So I tried to put them in a container** (and routerview in the container), like this:
Routing:
{
path: "/user/",
component: Container,
///
children: [
{ path: "/user/:id", component: AlbumView },
{ path: "/user/album:id", component: PhotoView },
],
},
}
[image: new routing set-up, with multiple children]

This doesn’t work, only the albumview shows.
When I click on each album, it's just set the url as expected but routing won't work. What do I do wrong?
What's the best solution to fix this?

```
I grab the id in both views like this
 data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
```

Comment: Just a passing comment—that’s one beautifully illustrated question with a lot of details! Sometimes I wish more questions are as clear and as well-explained like this one. Amazing work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When routing to a component with route params, a property is created on the `$route.params` object for each matched param.

So if there are multiple params in the route definition with the same name: `id`, only the last one will be stored in the `$route.params.id` property, the others will be overwritten and lost.

Give the params different names in the route definition:

```js
{
  path: "/user/:idUser/albums/:idAlbum",
  component: PhotoView
},
```

Access these in the component as:

- `this.$route.params.idUser`
- `this.$route.params.idAlbum`

Comment: THANK YOU!  I choose to skip the children nesting, and go with :   { path: "/user/:idUser", component: AlbumView },
  { path: "/user/album/:idAlbum", component: PhotoView },,